# How can I point the 'history' command to an alternate file?

Tags: linux, file, history

On my development machine, I have a number of different environments, each of which maintaining an own history file with a dedicated name. This is a customer requirement which I can not change.

If I have activated one of these environments, a 'history' command will always list the contents of the current environments history-file which is ok.

However, if I want to look up something in the history of another environment, I can only do this by opening a new shell and loading the respective environment. But what I want to do is to tell 'history' from which file it should read it's input **without** opening a new session and loading the environment in question.

Just 'grep'ing the alternative history-file is not a satisfying option as I want the entire output (e.g. timestamps) to be formatted properly.

The question is: How can I point 'history' to process an alternative file? Trying with

`$ HISTFILE=/path/to/other-histfile history`

didn't help, nor did

`$ export HISTFILE=/path/to/other-histfile; history`

I could write a perl script to do produce the oputput I want. But perhaps there is a way to do this out of the box?

EDIT: An environment is activated by a script which sources all settings which are relevant for the history processing.

`useEnv()` is an alias which basically looks like this:

```
useEnv()
{
export HISTFILE=/some/directory/.bash_history.$ENVNAME
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
}
```

EDIT, SOLUTION: KamilCuk had the solution which works for me, see his answer below. Here is my summary:

- You can write an alias or a script which first clears [**-c**] the history list (but leaves $HISTFILE untouched), and then reads [**-r**] the alternative history file.
- Upon the next **history** call the content of the alternative file is displayed.
- Then, clear the history again and read back $HISTFILE
- like so:

`$ history -c -r /path/to/otherfile; history; history -c -r $HISTFILE`

Comment: Please add more details to your question. How exactly do you select/load a specific environment?

Comment: `I want to look up something in the history of another environment` but why not just `grep something /path/to/other-histfile`?

Comment: There is a customer script which sources all the settings, all done within bash.

Comment: @KamilCuk Just read the opening question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information. How do you call the "customer script"? How does it manipulate the history? Maybe you can wrap this in a script or function.

Comment: @Bodo I have added some information. But the entire alias-scripting is a some-thousand lines thing which I can not post here (and is an NDA matter).  But in fact, the question is independent from this, as I just want to know: Can I make 'history' process a different file than the regular one?

Comment: @KamliCuk's solution seems to work for me. I'll put this in a script, seems to do what I want. Thank you!

Comment: I also thought about something like this and would extend it to save the current history and maybe switch back to the previous history file at the end.

Answer (score 2):

`HISTFILE` is the file where the command history is **saved** (and read on startup, and also it's the default for `history` command when no filename argument is given, but mostly it's for saving).

Clear *current history list* and then *read* another history file to the *current history list*:

```
history -c
history -r /path/to/other-histfile
```

You might want to modify `HISTFILE` too, so it does not get saved.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a viable solution. I wasn't aware of the meaning of the -c and -r arguments. The man page does not tell much about them. Thank you and upvote.

Comment: The final solution might need to save the history before clearing it and maybe afterwards clear again and load the previous history file

Comment: As far as I have seen, the '-c' argument does not clear the history-***file**, but only the history ***list**. Having tries KamilKuc's suggestion, the history was empty after the first step. But $HISTFILE was still untouched. With ```history -r $HISTFILE``` you get the history listing back. That's very close to what I need.

Comment: You can do this on the commandline in one wash:
 ```$ history -c -r /path/to/otherfile; history; history -r $HISTFILE ```
If you call history again, things are back to previous state. As an alias, say ```althist``` or so, you have what you need. You have to provide a ```$1``` argument to the alias though: ```$ althist otherfile```

Comment: Missed a **-c** arg but can not anymore edi my comments. See opening question for a correct summary.